# libedit not found: Centos, installing openssh

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, openssh, file-not-found

I wnt to install `openssh` from  http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/openssh.html   (I don't want to use packages with yum)

--with-libedit[=PATH]   Enable libedit support for sftp

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/bin/openssh \
--sysconfdir=/etc/ssh --with-md5-passwords \
--with-libedit=/usr/lib --with-pam
```

But I have this error:

```
...
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking if /usr/bin/pkg-config knows about libedit... no
checking for el_init in -ledit... no
configure: error: libedit not found
```

Checking 1:

```
# find /usr/lib/ -iname "libedit.*"
/usr/lib/libedit.so
/usr/lib/libedit.so.0.0.27
/usr/lib/libedit.so.0
#
```

**INI:EDIT 1**

```
# ls -Al /usr/lib/libedit*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     21 Nov 27 08:47 /usr/lib/libedit.so -> /usr/lib/libedit.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     17 Jun 13 10:12 /usr/lib/libedit.so.0 -> libedit.so.0.0.27
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 159968 Aug 19  2010 /usr/lib/libedit.so.0.0.27
# 

# rpm -qa | grep libedit
libedit-2.11-4.20080712cvs.1.el6.i686
# 


# rpm -qi libedit-devel
package libedit-devel is not installed
# 

# rpm -qi libedit
Name        : libedit                      Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 2.11                              Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 4.20080712cvs.1.el6           Build Date: Thu 19 Aug 2010 08:40:35 AM UTC
Install Date: Sat 13 Jun 2015 10:12:01 AM UTC      Build Host: c6b3.bsys.dev.centos.org
Group       : System Environment/Libraries   Source RPM: libedit-2.11-4.20080712cvs.1.el6.src.rpm
Size        : 166800                           License: BSD
Signature   : RSA/8, Sun 03 Jul 2011 04:22:56 AM UTC, Key ID 0946fca2c105b9de
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
URL         : http://www.thrysoee.dk/editline/
Summary     : The NetBSD Editline library
Description :
Libedit is an autotool- and libtoolized port of the NetBSD Editline library.
It provides generic line editing, history, and tokenization functions, similar
to those found in GNU Readline.
#
```

**END:EDIT 1**

But I'm receiving the same error...

¿How solve this?

Comment: ls "/usr/lib/libedit*" does return something? Also, from this thread: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/openssh/dev/45870 it may look in /usr/lib/lib. Try to run "bash -x ./configure bla bla" and see where it's actually looking for libedit.

Comment: is `libedit-devel` rpm package installed? (`rpm -qi libedit-devel`); and, are you sure you are on i686, not x86_64?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install http://thrysoee.dk/editline/ (libedit-20150325-3.1.tar.gz) but doesn't work!!!

Later I installed libedit-devel  package but was the similar result (doesn't work!)

Then taking care of packages I decided to uninstall!!!

```
#yum remove libedit.i686
...
Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================================================================================================================
Package                                   Arch                     Version                                      Repository                                                Size
================================================================================================================================================================================
Removing:
libedit                                   i686                     2.11-4.20080712cvs.1.el6                     @anaconda-CentOS-201410241409.i386/6.6                   163 k
Removing for dependencies:
firstboot                                 i686                     1.110.15-1.el6                               @anaconda-CentOS-201410241409.i386/6.6                   650 k
ipa-client                                i686                     3.0.0-42.el6.centos                          @anaconda-CentOS-201410241409.i386/6.6                   299 k
libedit-devel                             i686                     2.11-4.20080712cvs.1.el6                     @base                                                     40 k
ntp                                       i686                     4.2.6p5-1.el6.centos                         @anaconda-CentOS-201410241409.i386/6.6                   1.6 M
openssh-clients                           i686                     5.3p1-104.el6                                @anaconda-CentOS-201410241409.i386/6.6                   1.3 M
python-meh                                noarch                   0.12.1-3.el6                                 @anaconda-CentOS-201410241409.i386/6.6                   186 k
system-config-date                        noarch                   1.9.60-2.el6.centos                          @anaconda-CentOS-201410241409.i386/6.6                   3.6 M
system-config-date-docs                   noarch                   1.0.11-1.el6                                 @anaconda-CentOS-201410241409.i386/6.6                   1.5 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================================================================================================================
Remove        9 Package(s)

Installed size: 9.2 M
```

Later install package (uninstalled libedit.i686) and libedit-devel.i686

```
# yum install libedit.i686 libedit-devel.i686

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================================================================================================================
Package                                     Arch                               Version                                                Repository                          Size
================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
libedit                                     i686                               2.11-4.20080712cvs.1.el6                               base                                73 k
libedit-devel                               i686                               2.11-4.20080712cvs.1.el6                               base                                26 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================================================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)

Total download size: 99 k
Installed size: 203 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
```

I found another error (but libedit  error was solved) and is other question not related with this thread!

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/bin/openssh \
--sysconfdir=/etc/ssh --with-md5-passwords \
--with-libedit --with-pam
...



# find /. -name "libedit.*"
/./usr/lib/libedit.so
/./usr/lib/libedit.so.0.0.27
/./usr/lib/pkgconfig/libedit.pc
/./usr/lib/libedit.so.0
/./usr/local/lib/libedit.so
/./usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libedit.pc
/./usr/local/lib/libedit.la
/./usr/local/lib/libedit.a
/./usr/local/lib/libedit.so.0.0.53
/./usr/local/lib/libedit.so.0
/./usr/local/libedit-20150325-3.1/libedit.pc.in
/./usr/local/libedit-20150325-3.1/libedit.pc
/./usr/local/libedit-20150325-3.1/src/.libs/libedit.so
/./usr/local/libedit-20150325-3.1/src/.libs/libedit.la
/./usr/local/libedit-20150325-3.1/src/.libs/libedit.lai
/./usr/local/libedit-20150325-3.1/src/.libs/libedit.a
/./usr/local/libedit-20150325-3.1/src/.libs/libedit.so.0.0.53
/./usr/local/libedit-20150325-3.1/src/.libs/libedit.so.0
/./usr/local/libedit-20150325-3.1/src/libedit.la
```

Answer (score 0):

### I found this issue while installing asterisk 17 on CentOS 7.

**Just download and follow these steps to solve this issue**

[libedit-3.0](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/libedit-3.0-12.20121213cvs.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) **and** [libedit-devel-3.0](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/libedit-devel-3.0-12.20121213cvs.el7.x86_64.rpm.html)

```
1. yum remove libedit.
2. yum localinstall libedit-3.0-12.20121213cvs.el7.x86_64.rpm
3. yum localinstall libedit-devel-3.0-12.20121213cvs.el7.x86_64.rpm
```